# I get WebClientResponseException$ServiceUnavailable error when I use @LoadBalanced annotated WebClient.Builder

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-rest, spring-webclient

When I use @LoadBalanced annotation for WebClient.Builder I get following stack trace from external API.
The demo I wrote before this was returning hardcoded data and I use EurekaServer. That application also giving error because I didn't annotated my WebClient.Builder with @LoadBalanced so how can I use this for both usage I believe its happening because server has one or multiple instances.

MainApp

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
public class MovieInfoServiceApplication {

    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    public WebClient.Builder getWebClientBuilder() {
        return WebClient.builder();

    }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MovieInfoServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

RestController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/movies")
public class MovieRestController {

api key field

    @Autowired
    private WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;

@RequestMapping("/{movieId}")
    public Movie getMovieById(@PathVariable("movieId") int movieId) {
Movie movieDetails = webClientBuilder
                .build()
                .get()
                .uri("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/" + movieId + "?api_key=" + apiKey)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(Movie.class).block();

        return new Movie(movieId, movieDetails.getTitle(), movieDetails.getOverview());
}
}
```

Stack trace

```
500 Internal Server Error from GET http://localhost:8082/movies/550
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$InternalServerError: 500 Internal Server Error from GET http://localhost:8082/movies/550
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException.create(WebClientResponseException.java:201)
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ 500 from GET http://movie-info-service/movies/550 [DefaultWebClient]
Stack trace:
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException.create(WebClientResponseException.java:201)
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultClientResponse.lambda$createException$1(DefaultClientResponse.java:209)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:100)
```

After https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/issues/295#issuecomment-414206032 this implementation

MainApp

```
@SpringBootApplication

@EnableEurekaClient

public class MovieInfoServiceApplication {



    @Bean

    WebClient webClient(LoadBalancerClient loadBalancerClient) {

        return WebClient.builder()

                .filter(new LoadBalancerExchangeFilterFunction(loadBalancerClient))

                .build();

    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(MovieInfoServiceApplication.class, args);

    }



}
```

RestController

```
@RestController

@RequestMapping("/movies")

public class MovieRestController {



    @Value("${api.key}")

    private String apiKey;



    @Autowired

    private WebClient webClient;





    @RequestMapping("/{movieId}")

    public Movie getMovieById(@PathVariable("movieId") int movieId) {



        Movie movieDetails = webClient

                .get()

                .uri("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/" + movieId + "?api_key=" + apiKey)

                .retrieve()

                .bodyToMono(Movie.class)

                .block();





        return new Movie(movieId, movieDetails.getTitle(), movieDetails.getOverview());



    }

}
```

Error

```
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun May 03 19:15:51 EET 2020

There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).

503 Service Unavailable from UNKNOWN 

org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$ServiceUnavailable: 503 Service Unavailable from UNKNOWN 

    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException.create(WebClientResponseException.java:207)

    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 

Error has been observed at the following site(s):

    |_ checkpoint ⇢ 503 from GET https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/551?api_key=apikeyvalue [DefaultWebClient]

Stack trace:

        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException.create(WebClientResponseException.java:207)

        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultClientResponse.lambda$createException$1(DefaultClientResponse.java:209)

        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:100)

        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:92)

        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121)

        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextStart.java:103)

        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:287)
```

Comment: check if the workaround here solves your issue https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/issues/295#issuecomment-414206032

Comment: I thought that was the case but unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: When you say it didn’t work, post EXACTLY what didn’t eork, error message, implementation. Im not going to sit and guess all night

Comment: When I re-implemented that workaround for what happened, it actually worked now, I guess I did it wrong at the beginning.
I thought you weren't sure and just gave the link for try, I didn't know you wanted to follow along.
Thank you.

Comment: i like to help people, but it is very hard to help people when people usually just answer "it didn't work" i always like to know exactly what did not work so that one can work more on the problem at hand.

Comment: this is what I get as an error , don't mind my last comment please.
503 Service Unavailable from UNKNOWN 
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$ServiceUnavailable: 503 Service Unavailable from UNKNOWN 
 at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException.create(WebClientResponseException.java:207)
 Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
 |_ checkpoint ⇢ 503 from GET https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/551?api_key=apikey [DefaultWebClient]

Comment: it says straight up, you are calling UNKNOWN and nothing is answering at the address UNKNOW (becuase thats not a valid uri) so you get a 503 back

Comment: It happens when I annotate my WebClient bean with LoadBalanced annotation. If I remove annotation this service works fine on the other hand I have another service using same implementation for WebClient it works with LoadBalanced annotation and gives same http 503 error when I don't use it. Only different between these two service is the one working with annotation makes requests to eureka discovery server, other one makes requests to external api.  I cant use same implementation for two service, I wonder if there is a generic way to use WebClient in both scenario

Comment: wait, you are trying to call a non-eureka registered service using a `@LoadBalanced` webclient? becuase that is obviously NOT going to work.

Comment: All my services registered to eureka server. My app works like this ; A service calling the B and C services through service discovery. B service makes request to external API, A service collect data from other two service and returns it. A works with @LoadBalanced , B doesn't.

Comment: it's been a while, but if i remember correctly, the `@LoadBalanced` client is only for registering your service with eureka. It calls eureka during startup and registers it using that webclient. All other calls have to be made with another client, but you do the calls to their service names instead of public uri's.